# What url do I use when serving a photo stored outside the web root?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to figure out how to serve photos that are stored outside the web root. I know that I shouldn't store photos (that were uploaded by the user) inside the web root for security reasons, but this seems to present a problem. How do I show users these photos? Here is what I have so far:

```
app.get('/photos', function(req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('./photos/photo_1.jpg', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        pic = data;
    });
}
```

The problem is I don't really know what to do from here. For a photo stored inside the web root I would do something like the following:

```
<img src="inside-web-root-directory/pics/some_pic.jpg" alt="pic">
```

I'm just not sure what to put inside `src` for photos NOT stored inside the web root. What should I do?

Comment: If the image is stored outside the web root there's no way to refer to it directly. You'll need some sort of server-side code to retrieve and serve it.

Comment: ^^ Yes, you must use php to grab it. Alternatively, you can store the image in the main root but make the image name in such a way that a user can't simply go from image1 to image2.jpg but instead would need to know the hashed full name to retrieve. It's not 100% safe but it is MUCH easier to implement

Comment: @ProfileTwist This question is clearly tagged with Node.js... it has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Well then... the answer is you CAN NOT. As @MikeW explained, you must use the server-side code. Alternatively, you can rename the images with long hash names and place them within the public folder of the server as I explained earlier.

Comment: @ProfileTwist I recommend reading up on Node.js:  http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just retrieving photos directly from some other location, you might as well have them in the web server's document root, as it is just as insecure.  You can use Express' static module for this.  I don't recommend it in this case.

What I do in situations like this is accept an ID number which refers to the record in a database containing other information (who uploaded it, when, etc.), and contains the real file name of the asset on disk.  That asset is named either by ID number or some other GUID (without file name extension), and is returned upon request.  For example:

```
app.get('/photos/:id', function (req, res) {
    // Use req.params.id to look up your image in a database
    // Use res.sendfile to send the real file on disk to the user
});
```